# Merge Arrays from Structures

Tags: vba, data-structures, outlook

I am trying to run DASL query on all subfolders of outlook mailbox and then merge the results into the main array after each folder loop. I have tried the below but unable to achieve. Any guidance or suggestion will be helpful

```
strFilter = "@SQL=" & "urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived <> ''"
Dim eFolder as Outlook.Folder =  myNamespace.Folders("ABC@xyz.com").Folders("Inbox")

Dim oT As Outlook.Table = eFolder.GetTable(strFilter)
Dim RowCount As Integer = oT.GetRowCount

Dim VarArray As Array
VarArray = oT.GetArray(RowCount)

 'THIS DOES NOT WORK ----- VarArray=VarArray.Union(Ot.GetArray(RowCount))
```

I have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a new array manually by iterating over all entries in the array from the table. For example, this is how you can iterate over all items:

```
'Get all items in Inbox that meet the filter 
 Set oTable = oFolder.GetTable(Filter) 

 On Error GoTo Err_Trap 
 varArray = oTable.GetArray(oTable.GetRowCount) 

   'Number of rows is the second dimension of the array 
   ubRows = UBound(varArray, 2) 
   'Number of columns is the first dimension of the array 
   ubCols = UBound(varArray) 

   'Array is zero-based 
   'Rows corrspond to items in the table, so for each item... 
   For j = 0 To ubRows 
     'Columns correspond to properties in the table, print the value of each property 
     For i = 0 To ubCols 
       Debug.Print varArray(i, j) 
     Next 
   Next 
 Exit Sub 

Err_Trap: 
 Debug.Print "Error#:" & Err.Number & " Desc: " & Err.Description 
 Resume Next
```